# Add class to any element with CKEditor

Tags: wysiwyg

Is there a way to add class to any element through CKEditor?

Here is an example: I create a list with CKEditor and I want to add a class to the `ul` tag. Or maybe on one of the `li`.

Everything without opening the source of course.

Is there any way to achieve that? (with CKEditor or with another WYSIWYG)

Comment: CKeditor is quite extendable, if you can't find an existing plugin which does it you could write your own

Comment: You can add styles to the editor from the admin per element, it just requires highlighting the elements and selecting the Styles drop down as to what to apply.

Comment: @Kevin Of course, yes. But, the issue is that that solution add a `span` with the class around your selection. Here I just want to add the class directly to my slection

Comment: It doesn’t for me. If I say an li tag can have a class, the class is added. Same for a tags.

Answer (score 5):

You can configure custom styles in 'Text formats and editors':

1. Visit /admin/config/content/formats, and click Configure for any
   format using CKEditor
2. Ensure the 'Styles' button is in your active toolbar
3. Click 'Styles dropdown' under CKEditor plugin settings
4. Add class|style values per the instructions

Using your example, you could add entries like:

```
ul.myListClass|Special List
li.myItemClass|Special List Item
```

This would make the styles 'Special List' and 'Special List Item' appear in the styles dropdown anytime the user's cursor is anywhere in an `ul` or `li`. If they choose 'Special List', the class 'myListClass' would be added to the nearest `ul`. If they choose 'Special List Item', 'myItemClass' gets added to the current `li`.

This assumes current versions of Drupal 8. I'm not sure about Drupal 7, but I assume up-to-date versions would have similar functionality.

Comment: What if I want to add `myListClass` class to any HTML element (like p, a, span, div, ul, ol, li, table, tr, td and many more)? Is there a way to do that?